# visibilitychange in mobile safari standalone mode

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, lockscreen, iphone-standalone-web-app

The Visibility API doesn't work in standalone mode on iOS.

I need to know if the phone was unlocked with my app in the foreground so that I can check for an update, but nothing seems to work.

I don't get the `visibilitychange` event.  `document.hidden` is false, and `document.visibilityState` is "visible" when the phone is locked.  I've also found that timers like `setTimeout` and `requestAnimationFrame` continue to function while the screen is locked, so I can't use the hacks I've found to detect that state.  Has anyone had any success with this?  Are there any api's that will fail if the screen is locked?

Comment: Please upload the code  you have done this far

Answer (score -2):

I'm answering here since the system does not let me add a comment.
I did search for this also, and did not find this.
It worked before iOS 11.0.2, but I guess that does not help you very much.