# Why is my fetch keepalive call on page unload failing in Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, cors, page-lifecycle, visibilitychange

I need to send back a bit of data for reporting when the user closes or leaves a specific page.  So I set up an API endpoint and am using window.fetch with the keepalive flag set to make sure that the call completes even if the page unloads completely.

The Javascript call in question looks like this:

```
async onLeavingPage() {
    (preparing data for call)
    const response = await fetch(
        (url),
        {
            keepalive: true,
            method: "POST",
            mode: "cors",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                Authorization: axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"]
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({})
        }
    );
    console.log(response);
}
```

I'm calling it by watching for the pagevisibility event and calling it when the page is hidden or terminated, using the page-lifecycle library.

```
lifecycle.addEventListener("statechange", (e) => {
            if (e.newState === "hidden" || e.newState === "terminated") {
                this.onLeavingPage();
            }
        });
```

The preferred behavior is for the call to be completed, even if the page is reloaded or another link is clicked on.  But thanks to this CORS error, it's not happening.  It works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but in Safari it fails with this error message in the console:

> Fetch API cannot load (api endpoint) due to access control checks.

The same fetch call works in Safari if it's called in any other circumstance (like, say, clicking a link or minimizing and then maximizing the page), so it's something specific to calling it on page unload.

Comment: You may be hitting a known bug in Safari, related to visibilitychange not firing as expected during page navigations; see https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=151234. Maybe try testing in Safari Technology Preview, and see if it works as expected there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57393717/441757 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/48101355/441757 may be caused by the same underlying problem.

Comment: I think the workaround you might want to try is to listen for the `pagehide` event, which does reliably fire in Safari even when `visibilitychange` doesn’t.

Comment: I had it console.log when visibility changes.  As far as I can see, it's firing as expected, even in Safari.  I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/page-lifecycle to detect lifecycle events, and it has code to handle Safari not firing visibilitychange consistently.  Although I wonder if the fact that Safari is using beforeunload as a replacement might have something to do with it.

Comment: OK, yeah I guessed that library must be written to be smart enough to abstract away the Safari problem. But anyway, I still wonder if the CORS error is in fact a side effect of some other problem — not the other way around. I guess one way to isolate that would be to retry it all in a test environment where the frontend code and the API endpoint are same-origin rather than cross-origin. If it didn’t work even when the request is same-origin, then you’d know the root cause wasn’t a CORS issue — and of course on th other hand, if it did work, you’d know that cause really has to be a CORS issue.

Comment: You probably want to update the question to paste in the exact error messages the browser is logging in the Safari Web Inspector console, as well as pasting in all the request headers for all the requests (including the preflight OPTIONS request), and the response headers. And you should check the HTTP status code for both the OPTIONS and POST responses. You can get to all that from the Network tab in Safari Web Inspector.